# Continuous maps on the chaotic topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Iv'e been asked to prove the following statement:
**Show that any map $f : M → N$ is continuous if the sets are endowed with a generic
topology $\mathcal{O}_M$ on $M$ and the chaotic topology $\mathcal{O}_N = \{ ∅, N \}$ on $N$.**
Since a continuous map is one in which $\text{preim}_f(V)\in \mathcal{O}_M$ when $V\in\mathcal{O}_N$, I would say that the necessary condition for the map to be continuous is that $\text{preim}_f(N)\in\mathcal{O}_M$ and $\text{preim}_f(\emptyset)\in\mathcal{O}_M$, but this would mean that not every map $f:M\rightarrow N$ is continuous.
Is there something that Im missing?

Comment: Chaotic topology? ;) this a funny word for indiscrete or trivial

Comment: @FShrike I think the reason for that name is that every sequence will converge to every element of the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ (why?). I also hint to you that if $f:M\to N$ we are guaranteed $f^{-1}(N)\in\mathcal{O}_M$, always. Think carefully about what the preimage is doing there.